# How do I resize this <img>?

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to resize the second img with css. I can resize it with inline style rules but I'm not allowed to use them. I can resize the img right above this one with CSS just fine. I know how to make it work but I don't know why this way doesn't work; it doesn't make any sense to me. May I please have some help here? Thanks.

### HTML

```html
<div id="social-block">
<a href="">
   <img src="media/f.webp" alt="Facebook brand logo">
</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UByhxXvmX8o">
   <img src="media/y.png" alt="YouTube brand logo">
</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#left {
    width: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EFFFFF;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 10px solid orange;
}

#social-block img:nth-of-type(1){
    width: 20px;
}

#social-block img:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the HTML code you wrote 
in order to use the css style you have writen just give the secand img the id `left` so the HTML code should look like

```
<div id="social-block">
   <a href=""><img src="media/f.webp" alt="Facebook brand logo"></a>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UByhxXvmX8o"><img src="media/y.png" 
        alt="YouTube brand logo" id="left"></a>
</div>
```

and also make sure you add the css code inside a `<style>` tag or in your css file

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
<div id="social-block">
    <a href=""><img id="fb" src="media/f.webp" alt="Facebook brand logo"></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UByhxXvmX8o"><img id="yt" src="media/y.png" alt="YouTube brand logo"></a>
</div>
```

With this CSS

```
#fb{
    width: 20px;
}
#yt{
    width: 75px;
}
```

EDIT:
This may work

```
#social-block>a>img:nth-of-type(1){
    width: 20px;
}

#social-block>a>img:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 75px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works but I'm wondering why it doesn't work the other way. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I think maybe is this ```img:nth-of-type(1)```. Try the thing that I will add to the answer

Answer (score 0):

when you use nth-of-type your tag must be brothers(all tag must in same level and inner on tag ) replace your code by below :

```
#left {
    width: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EFFFFF;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 10px solid orange;
}

#social-block a:nth-of-type(1) img{
    width: 20px;
}

#social-block a:nth-of-type(2) img {
    width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Good explanation.

Comment: yrw . please make answere correct

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly using `:nth-of-type` as both will fall into the category of `:nth-of-type(1)` as they are not globally searched but searched their numbers based to their parents.

**Best Way:**

Add a class to each of them, like `.img-1` and `.img-2` and go on.

**Editing your Way:**

Instead of adding `child-nos` to img, do them to `anchor element` ...

```css
#left {
    width: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EFFFFF;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 10px solid orange;
}

#social-block a:nth-of-type(1) img{
    width: 20px;
}

#social-block a:nth-of-type(2) img {
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="social-block">

<a href="">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Facebook brand logo">
</a>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UByhxXvmX8o">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="YouTube brand logo">
</a>

</div>
```